# Xamarin.iOS: different behaviour on device and simulator

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I need to detect if my code runs on Xamarin.iOS and for this reason I wrote next code:

```
bool isIOS()
{
   try
   {
      var assmbl = Assembly.Load("Xamarin.iOS.dll");
      if (assmbl == null) return false;

      var classType = assmbl.GetType("UIKit.UIDevice");
      if (classType == null) return false; // HERE IS THE PROBLEM !!!

      var prop = classType.GetProperty("CurrentDevice");
      if (prop == null) return false;

      var currDevice = prop.GetValue(null);
      if (currDevice == null) return false;

      var sType = currDevice.GetType();

      prop = sType.GetProperty("SystemName");
      if (prop == null) return false;

      var name = prop.GetValue(currDevice) as string;

      return (name == "iOS");
   }
   catch
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

The problem is that assmbl.GetType("UIKit.UIDevice") returns correct Type on simulator and this code works as expected, but on real device it returns null.

Also if I call assmbl.GetTypes() the method returns about 1000 types on simulator and 100+ on the device.

UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemName works fine on both simulator and device, but I can't use it directly as the code should work in Xamarin and non-Xamarin applications.

What could be the reason of such behaviour?

Comment: have you checked your linker settings?

Comment: @Jason Linker behaviour is set to "Link Framework SDKs Only", but I've also tried "Link All" without success.

Comment: either of those setting would strip out any unused libraries, which seems like it would cause this problem

Comment: @Jason Indeed it works fine with Linker behaviour set to "Don't Link". But this is not a default value when new project is created, so now the question is how to make it work out-of-the-box? :) The code is a part of a library and we can't force users to change linker settings.

Comment: @Vsevolod iOS projects bound for the App Store have to use at least "Link Framework SDKs Only" in order to remove the code that refers to non-used entitlements. In Enterprise or private distros, this would not apply of course, but your app size will be quite huge.

Comment: why isn't checking for "Xamarin.iOS.dll" alone good enough to determine that the library is running on iOS?

Comment: Okey , it's insterting for the physical device , I will check the reason .In addittion ,do you mind using  [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-information?tabs=ios) to check the device info ?